# shapes don't show up on window

Tags: python, pygame, shapes

shapes in pygame don't show up on my window.

i have tried updating the display and writing the code for the object in different ways but no progress.

```
#COLOURS
red = 255, 0, 0
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

pygame.draw.circle(win, black , (200, 200),50)
pygame.draw.line(win, (0,0,0), [100, 100], [200, 200], 10)
pygame.draw.line(win, black, [210, 150], [220, 150], 5)
pygame.draw.line(win, white, (5,0), (13, 0), 10)
pygame.display.update()

win.fill(green)
pygame.display.update()
```

the colour of the screen did change to green but the lines are not shown.

Comment: try filling with green before you draw the lines, it looks like the lines get drawn but immediatley overwritten with green

Comment: @Aemyl yes, that was the problem. thanks